# how to get second td for tr in dynamic click tr column

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get second td text value.when i click any tr column must show to second td text value

```css
td:hover{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>row1</th><th>row2</th><th>row3</th><th>row4</th><th>row5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-class="weeks">
      <td class="cls">1</td><td class="cls">2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-class="weeks">
      <td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('td').click(function(){//add click event on each td
  console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text());//log the result of getting the second td text
})
```

```css
td:hover{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>row1</th><th>row2</th><th>row3</th><th>row4</th><th>row5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-class="weeks">
      <td class="cls">1</td><td class="cls">2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-class="weeks">
      <td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text()
```

1. Using `.closest('tr')` get the row of the clicked td
2. Using `.find('td:nth-child(2)')` get the second td of the clicked row
3. Using `.text()` get the text of the second td of the clicked row